# c# expressions and loop beauty

Tags: c#, while-loop, expression

This is probably pretty subjective, but how do people generally lay out their loop control in C# when the control variable is updated in the loop? The pedant in me doesn't like the separate declaration and repetition involved. eg.

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    //do something with line

    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

The C coder in me wants to change this to

```
while (string line = reader.ReadLine() != null)
{
    //do something with line
}
```

but C#'s expressions don't seem to work that way :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't declare a variable inside an expression.

You can write

```
string line;
while (line = reader.ReadLine() != null)
```

To make it clearer, I prefer to write

```
string line;
while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
```

However, the best alternative is

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(path) {

}
```

This will perform equivalently.
If you're reading some other stream, you can create an extension method that uses the previous syntax to enable `foreach` loops.

Comment: And don't forget to declare the variable before.

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov: I didn't.

Answer (score 7):

Options:

1) Declare the variable the loop, but assign it in the condition:

```
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
}
```

2) Use a for loop instead:

```
for (string line = reader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = reader.ReadLine())
{
}
```

3) Create an extension method to turn a reader into an `IEnumerable<String>` and then use:

```
foreach (string line in reader.ReadLines())
{
}
```

Personally I like the last one where possible - otherwise I'd use the first form.

Comment: You could make that last one a `var`, no? I mean, if your colleagues cannot figure out that the result of `ReadLines` is a `string`, the solution is not explicit typing but immediate sacking :-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I could, but I'm not sure there's any benefit in doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer:

```
string line;
while (line = reader.ReadLine() != null)
{
  ...
}
```

There's always the for construct as an alternative though:

```
for (string line = reader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = reader.ReadLine())
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually write something like:

```
string line;
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that repeating the `reader.ReadLine()` expression isn't good. One way is to use `while(true)` and `break`:

```
while(true)
{
  string line = reader.ReadLine();
  if(line == null)
    break;

  //do something with line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public static IEnumerable<R> ToSequence<T, R>(this T self, 
    Func<T, R> yielder, Func<R, bool> condition)
{
    R result = yielder(self, R);
    while (condition(result))
    {
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

and then use it something like this:

```
foreach (var line in reader.ToSequence(
    (r) => r.ReadLine(), 
    (line) => line != null))
{
    // do some stuff to line
}
```

or would you prefer:

```
foreach (var line in reader.NotNull(r => r.ReadLine()))
{
    // do some stuff to line...
}
```

that could be defined as:

```
public static IEnumerable<R> NotNull<T, R>(this T self, Func<T, R> yielder)
{
    return self.ToSequence(yielder, (r) => r != null);
}
```

Comment: Not sure that really improves the beauty ;)